# error while loading shared libraries when running prehook pod

Tags: openshift, web-deployment

I am new to OpenShift, I am deploying my flask app onto it, but encountered some problem. My app/container name is `flog`.

I set up a lifecycle prehook to ensure the database is created correctly for the app deployment. Here is my config(critical part):

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    deploymentconfig: flog
  strategy:
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
    resources: {}
    rollingParams:
      intervalSeconds: 1
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      pre:
        execNewPod:
          command:
            - flask
            - init
          containerName: flog
          env:
            - name: FLASK_APP
              value: wsgi.py
        failurePolicy: Abort
      timeoutSeconds: 600
      updatePeriodSeconds: 1
    type: Rolling
```

It works correctly in building but breaks in prehook

```
--> pre: Running hook pod ...
/opt/app-root/bin/python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, when I debug in terminal and type `python3` command, it works well.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a shell script into your image which in turns then runs your command. The shell script wrapper is needed as initialisation of the shell environment has the side effect of enabling the Python environment, including setting environment variables so it can find the Python shared library.

So change:

```
      command:
        - flask
        - init
```

to:

```
      command:
        - somescript
```

And in `somescript` have:

```
#!/bin/bash
flask init
```